# select distinct id with their latest activity

Tags: mysql

I have a **MYSQL** table structure as follows:

```
id         Activity
6298    2015-06-25 11:39:35
11141   2015-06-25 11:24:52
11141   2015-06-25 11:24:10
15048   2015-06-25 11:23:08
```

I want to get All ids and their latest activity :

so for the above example I want to get this:

```
id         Activity
6298    2015-06-25 11:39:35
11141   2015-06-25 11:24:52
15048   2015-06-25 11:23:08
```

at the moment I have to programatically go through each id and get their latest activity :

```
for each nextID in IDs :
    SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id= nextID  ORDER BY added DESC LIMIT
```

**Note:**

the table is huge because each id has many Activity(s).

**QUESTION:**

so my question is if there is a better way of doing it? for example one single query that could return me each id with its latest activity.

Comment: both tables are the same :/

Comment: oopse, :D, its fixed now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do a grouping. There is no shorter/better way. This is minimal statement for this:

```
select id, max(Activity) as Activity
from TableName
group by id
```

Comment: that was great mate, exactly what i need.